# Using flex to horitzontally align an image and text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flex to put an image and a text in 1 line. I'd like to horizontally align the two. `align-items: center` didn't work at all.

[image]

`align-items: flex-start;` kind of horizontally aligned the two, but it's not precise.

[image]

Not sure what's going on here. I'm looking align the two horizontally very precisely, help would be appreciated. I tried adding `style="vertical-align:middle;"` to `<img>`, but didn't work either.

```css
.entrepreneur {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.entrepreneur img {
  width: 35px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0; 
}

.entrepreneur #text {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="entrepreneur">
  <img src="img/Mark.jpg" alt="">
  <p id="text">Mark</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

flex direction by default is by row.  justify-content will center items on the horizontal axis and align-items will align items vertically.  You can change the direction to column and then these flip.

```css
#container{
display:
flex;
justify-content:space-evenly;
align-items:center;}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/350'>
<p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
}

p {
  margin-left: auto; // Just an example
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350">
  <p>TEXT...</p>
</div>
```

About `place-items`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items